# Flex3 can't access value of XML with brackets

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, xml-parsing, flex3

I have the following XML object:

```
<ns2:errorCode>
  3001
</ns2:errorCode>
```

How do I access the value if I only have a string saying errorCode.

I would like to do something like:

`xml['*::'+str]` 
where `xml` is the XML object with the above node and `str` is my string variable containing `"errorCode"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help. If anybody is interested this is how I solved it.

What was making the task difficult was the namespace. This works!

```
var t:XMLList = xml.*.(localName() =='errorCode');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check how to traverse XML structures in ActionScript3:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6b.html

`str = xml.errorCode` shall do the trick.

Comment: Tip: take a look at the namespace part. You will need it.